# How much hashMap operation can be called 'safe' at a time

Tags: android, sqlite, hashmap

I am developing an application in which I have a database with **5000** rows with **4** columns.

```
problem_id (int)
problem_no (string)
problem_title (string)
dacu (int)
```

I need to frequently query single items in a large scale like `1000 query to fetch problem_no based on problem_id` or `sometimes only one item`.

So I decided to query all the database rows and map them in a `hashMap` at runtime. I know hashmap insertion/query operation will take only `O(1)` or sometimes little more, so I only need 5000 operations I think. But how much space hashMap will take in this case? Would android `dalvik` be able to allocate them without any trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How much space will hashmap take?

It's an implementation detail that can vary between versions, devices, etc. As long as we understand that and look for an estimation only, you can actually measure it very easily. Android SDK includes a powerful suite of memory analysis tools. Check out Eclipse MAT (the best one in my eyes). You can take a heap snapshot when your hashmap is fully loaded, then use MAT to see how many bytes it takes. Make sure you sum up both the hash itself, the keys and the values (if I remember correctly MAT can do the math for you too (it can handle the core collections very well).

> Will dalvik be able to allocate?

For the sake of discussion let's say your hashmap takes 1MB of memory. To get a feeling if that's much, we need to understand the constraints of the system we live in. Dalvik limits the max size of your heap. The limitation varies per device. The minimum on very old devices is 16MB. Devices like Samsung Galaxy 2 have about 32MB-48MB and new devices like Galaxy 3 and 4 have more than 100MB.

The biggest memory hog in apps is usually bitmaps. Since every pixel can take as much as 4 bytes, a full screen bitmap can easily eat up a few MB of memory.

With this in mind, a toll of 1MB doesn't sound bad. It's comparable to a using a nice background image :) if your overall memory usage is low, you can distribute it as you see fit. The memory analysis tools (MAT or DDMS) let you know exactly how much memory your app is currently using, so you can easily estimate how much your total consumption will be.

**Other thoughts:**

- Caching things in memory to improve performance is usually a good idea. So your approach is a good one in my eyes (as long as you understand the memory implications).
- Since your memory hashmap is an optimization only, you can be extra careful and only do it when you have memory to spare. You can easily measure the amount of available heap (the is API for that) and make your decision accordingly. You can listen to low memory notification events (google about those). And you can even catch OutOfMemoryError exceptions of failed allocations and change your memory strategy in runtime.
- You are playing in a field where exact measurements are difficult. Be sure to QA on several devices and several versions of Android. To simulate low memory settings, try to use the oldest devices you can find.

Comment: I think it is the best answer with perfect explanation I've ever get. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that you will have absolutely no issues handling what you want in memory. Especially if those things are just primitives (no bitmaps).

I have used queries for up to 10k rows for caching in memory and had absolutely no issues in terms of memory for them.

The issue might happen when you need to process everything. Like how fast is it to get to a specific item, get all realated items etc..

One issue i have come accross was UI related. I tried to just fill an adapter and show it in a list with all 10k of rows which took about 7 seconds to complete. It was long time ago and i don't recall why exactly that happened, but what i am saying is that i would pay more attention to keep processing outside of the UI thread and manage that as much as possible rather than memory in your case.